# Streaming short[] is ~800 times slower than streaming byte[] - How to speed it up?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm transferring some large `short[]` arrays between processes using WCF in streaming mode, and I've run into a problem where the transfer is extremely slow.

I've done some tests, and it turns out that transferring a `short[]` array is around 800 times slower than using a `byte[]` array that contains the same number of bytes.

I assume that I must be doing something wrong here, since this behaviour cannot be expected.

**Given the reproduction below, can anyone suggest how I can speed it up?**

Note that I'm using streaming mode because the arrays are VERY large, and using non-streaming mode appears to use a total of three times the size of the array during transfer. (I'm wrapping a third-party 32-bit managed DLL in a separate process so that it can be called from a 64-bit C# program via WCF.)

Here's the server and client code. It seems quite long, but it's the shortest complete repro I can come up with...

The code is very simple: The WCF interface just has two methods, one taking a `short[]` parameter and another with a `byte[]` parameter. I test it by passing a `short[]` and a `byte[]` each containing the same number of bytes, and use a `Stopwatch` to time how long it takes.

To simplify things, I've put a copy of the `ITest` interface into both the client and the server source code to avoid having a third library - the real code does it properly.

These are both just console apps - you just need to compile and run them in any order, and then press ENTER in the client app to run the test.

Also note that I'm using .Net 4.6.2, but I have similar results with other versions.

**CLIENT**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Shared;

namespace Shared
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface ITest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void ShortTest(short[] array);

        [OperationContract]
        void ByteTest(byte[] array);
    }
}

namespace Client
{
    class Client
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int arraySizeInBytes = 10 * 1024 * 1024;

            var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None)
            {
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 4*arraySizeInBytes + 1024,
                SendTimeout            = TimeSpan.FromHours(1), // To allow debugging without timeouts.
                ReceiveTimeout         = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
                ReaderQuotas           = {MaxArrayLength = 4*arraySizeInBytes + 1024},
                TransferMode           = TransferMode.Streamed
            };

            var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ITest>(binding, "net.pipe://localhost/wcftest");
            var proxy = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

            short[] shorts = new short[arraySizeInBytes/sizeof(short)];

            for (int i = 0; i < shorts.Length; ++i) // Touch entire array to ensure memory allocated.
                shorts[i] = 1;

            byte[] bytes = new byte[arraySizeInBytes];

            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; ++i) // Touch entire array to ensure memory allocated.
                bytes[i] = 1;

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to call ByteTest() and ShortTest()");
                Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Calling ByteTest()");
                sw.Restart();
                proxy.ByteTest(bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("ByteTest() took " + sw.Elapsed);

                Console.WriteLine("Calling ShortTest()");
                sw.Restart();
                proxy.ShortTest(shorts);
                Console.WriteLine("ShortTest() took " + sw.Elapsed);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SERVER**

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading;
using Shared;

namespace Shared
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface ITest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void ShortTest(short[] array);

        [OperationContract]
        void ByteTest(byte[] array);
    }
}

namespace Server
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    class Server : ITest
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int arraySizeInBytes = 10 * 1024 * 1024;

            var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None)
            {
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 4*arraySizeInBytes + 1024,
                SendTimeout            = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),  // To allow debugging without timeouts.
                ReceiveTimeout         = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
                ReaderQuotas           = {MaxArrayLength = 4*arraySizeInBytes + 1024 },
                TransferMode           = TransferMode.Streamed
            };

            var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(new Server());
            serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), binding, "net.pipe://localhost/wcftest");
            serviceHost.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Server started. Close console to stop.");
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromHours(10));
        }

        public void ShortTest(short[] array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ShortTest() received array of size " + array.Length);
        }

        public void ByteTest(byte[] array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ByteTest() received array of size " + array.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

The results I get on my system are as follows:

```
Press <ENTER> to call ByteTest() and ShortTest()

Calling ByteTest()
ByteTest() took 00:00:00.0519079
Calling ShortTest()
ShortTest() took 00:00:41.9868413
Press <ENTER> to call ByteTest() and ShortTest()

Calling ByteTest()
ByteTest() took 00:00:00.0344547
Calling ShortTest()
ShortTest() took 00:00:41.4307394
Press <ENTER> to call ByteTest() and ShortTest()
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to speed up the transfer of the `short[]` data?

At the moment I expect I'll just have to convert it to a `byte[]` myself, but that is most unsatisfactory.

Comment: Would you be willing to use a different way of communicating across processes?; The documentation says that short[] should not be allowed for streaming at all: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.transfermode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 The documentation must be wrong since the code runs.

Comment: @usr Well, if it doesn't work out I'll just open my own MMF and stuff all the big binary data through that (and use WCF only for control flow).

Comment: @usr Yes, having done some more reading it appears that this sort of streaming (of `short[]`) doesn't really seem to be supported properly, as you suggest. It's going to be relatively easy to use `MemoryMappedFile` to pass the data via that route (and it should be pretty fast to copy the data in and out the MMF using `UnmanagedMemoryAccessor.ReadArray<T>()` and `UnmanagedMemoryAccessor.WriteArray<T>()`) so I think I will end up taking that approach.

Comment: I believe the ReadArray methods are extremely slow and reflection based if I recall correctly. Beware. Using memcpy to copy to and from an unmanaged buffer seems the safest option perf wise.